# mySQL update sort - order from table with unlimited childs after delete one or more

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
id | parent_id | order 
 1 |     0     |   1   
 2 |     1     |   1
 3 |     1     |   2
 4 |     1     |   3
 5 |     0     |   2
 6 |     0     |   3
 7 |     5     |   1
 8 |     5     |   2
```

it takes unlimited categories and childs in the same table by the parent_id.
I have a form with checkboxes to delete one or more and I want to re-ordering after delete one or more rows **group by parent_id**.

I have write this code:

```
mysql_query("SET @rownumber = 0;");
$sql_previous_order = "UPDATE `cms` SET `order` = (@rownumber:=@rownumber+1) ORDER by parent_id, `order` ASC";
```

but it not turn rownumber to zero (0) after change parent_id.

Comment: If you also add expected output it would be easier to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce an additional variable - p_id. Compare it with parent_id and reset rownumber to 0 when parent_id is changed. Like this

```
 SET @rownumber = 0;
 SET @p_id = 0;

select id, 
       CASE @p_id 
            WHEN parent_id THEN @rownumber:=@rownumber+1 
            ELSE @rownumber:=0 END as new_order,
       @p_id:=parent_id  as p_id
from cms
ORDER by parent_id ASC
;
```